# Symptoms and alternatives to overused OOP

Tags: c++, oop, reference

Lately I am losing my trust in OOP. I have already seen many
        complaints about common OOP misuses or just simple overuse. I do not
        mean the common confusion between is-a and has-a relationship. I mean
        stuff like the problems of ORM when dealing with relational databases,
        the excessive use of inheritance from C# and also several years of looking
        at code with the same false encapsulation belief that Scott Meyers
        mentions in the item 23 of Effective C++

I am interested in learning more about this and non OOP software
        patterns that can solve certain problems better than their OOP
        counterparts. I am convinced that out there there are many people
        giving good advice on how to use this as an advantage with non pure OOP
        languages such as C++.

Does anyone knows any good reference (author, book, article) to get
        started?

Please, notice that I am looking for two related but different things:

- Common misuses of OOP concepts (like item 23)
- Patterns where OOP is not the best solution (with alternatives)

Comment: Excessive use of inheritance??  What's that?

Comment: Using inheritance, where better is to use aggregation.

Comment: relational databases has it's own problems, that's why T-SQL and similar are developing into full languages, you can write Java SQL Server procedures, etc. Besides, there are good ORMs, I have written myself very usable one. and +1 for Noah's comment, really, what's excessive use of inheritance?!

Comment: It might be that "improper" or "unncessary" use of inheritance was intended instead of "Excessive"? I'm pretty sure I've seen WTF class hierarchies that could count as "improper"/"unnecessary".

Comment: @dzendras - why use aggregation when you can just copy/paste??

Comment: @Noah Roberts: Why copy and paste when you can just hack a script that generates the code for you? ;)

Comment: @Noah Roberts: My assumption was that developer has CTRL key broken and does not have a mouse :)

Comment: I'm not sure I trust this "Crazy Eddie" guy.

Answer (score 3):

Well I can recommend you a book [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857258).
Examples are in C# of course, but the idea of the book is universal. Not only it covers Agile but also focuses on bad practices and shows in examples how to convert bad code to a good code. It also contains descriptions of many design pattern and shows how to implement them in semi-real example of Payroll application.

Answer (score 2):

This has to be done but if you truly want to get away from OOP or at least take a look at concepts which are not OOP but are used with great effectiveness:  [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).  Try a new programming paradigm and then start seeing where you can apply much of the concepts back to OOP languages.  This addresses your second bullet, not in a direct way but trust me, it'll help more than you can think.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit odd that you mention C#.  It has *very* powerful keywords to keep the usual inheritance misery in check. The first one ought to be the *internal* keyword.  The notion of restricting the visibility to a *module*.  That concept is completely absent in C++, the build model just doesn't support it.  Otherwise a great concept, "I only trust the members of my team to get it right".  Of course you do.

Then there's the slammer one, the *sealed* keyword.  Extraordinary powerful, "the buck stops here, don't mess with me".  Used with surgical precision in the .NET framework, I've never yet found a case where *sealed* was used inappropriately.  Also missing in C++, but with obscure ways to get that working.

But yes, the WPF object model sucks fairly heavy.  Inheriting 6 levels deep and using backdoors like a dependency property is offensive.  Inheritance is hard, let's go shopping.

Comment: In C++, `static` restricts a function or object to file visibility.  No equivalent for `sealed` though (apart from a messy hack involving virtual inheritance).

Comment: Uhm... C++ does have a clear and simple way (the same as C) for limiting access to your classes to your own *module* (library/executable): Don't publish the objects in the headers. About sealing classes... I have known the trick for some time, both the simple not fool safe and the more complex and more expensive to write... but I have never felt that I really needed to *seal* a class.

Comment: In C++ you can seal a class by making its constructor private. (And then providing another way to instantiate it, of course.)

Comment: @David: It would often be useful to seal classes to ensure assumptions aren't violated, particularly for classes lacking virtual destructors that will cause UB if destructed via a pointer/reference to a parent class. A shining example would be `std::vector<T>` and the other containers, which people from time to time try to subclass as a search on SO will show you.

Comment: @JSBangs: Yeah, you can do that, but it makes a mess...  For one thing, that type is no longer default-constructible outside of methods or friends of the class.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to look at game engines.  For the most part, OOP has a tendency to cause slight performance decreases, and the gaming industry is seemingly obsessed with eliminating minor slowdowns (and sometimes ignoring large ones).  As such, their code, though usually written in a language that supports OOP, will end up using only those elements of OOP that are necessary for clean code / ease of maintenance that also balances performance.

EDIT:

Having said that, I don't know if I would really go look at Unreal.  They do some strange things for the sake of making their content pipeline easier for developers... it makes their code... well, look if you really want to know.

Comment: The games industry is largely obsessed with whatever programming paradigm was cool 15 years ago, because now they no longer perceive it as "too slow".

Comment: yep jalf, that's because they are all over OO now :)

Answer (score 1):

One common overuse is forcing OOP in programs/scripts that take some input, turn it to output, then exit (and not receiving input from anywhere else during the process). Procedural way is much cleaner in these cases.

Typical example of this is forcing OOP in PHP scripts.